# Can Entity Framework 4.1 designer "update model from database" for selected entities only?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, edmx, edmx-designer

**The situation:** Sometimes a database schema is not what you would consider an ideal representation of the system's information and you may not be able to change it. We have been using Entity Framework to create a nicer conceptual model to code against in situations like this. This means updating the model from the database and then changing it ourselves, either through the designer or through the .edmx file directly using a text editor.

**The problem:** When you update the model from the database, all your carefully made changes are thrown out the window. This can make adding new entities a real hassle as you are basically forced to do it through editing the .edmx file directly.

**The question:** Is there a way to get the Entity Framework to only update selected entities from from the database? Or is it possible to tell it to leave the rest of the model alone when adding a new entity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no way to make selective updates with built-in designer. Also the designer doesn't throw away all your changes. It usually doesn't touch conceptual model (except some rare occasions where it continuously renames some associations) and mapping but it always deletes storage model and override it with new definition. I worked without any problem with modifications to my conceptual model and mapping and running updates from the database.

Designer works as any other in Visual Studio - touching the generated code (storage model) is not supported feature. Once you do it you cannot use *Update from database* anymore.

There is [commercial tool](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) which probably supports better model updating - you can try a trial.

Answer (score 1):

If by updating selected entities, you mean just one or more tables, you can delete those tables from the model, and then add them back in individually to pull in changes tables by choosing them individually - I do that often as underlying tables are changed (especially during development).

You do end up losing any manual changes you made to those re-added entities after the entity/table was pulled into the model (i.e. I often rename my navigation properties and then after each re-import of the table I need to manually rename them again).