# Entity Framework 4 - Refresh specific tables when updating

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

Withn EF4, when using the Update Model from the Database wizard, it updates all tables that were previously imported and I don't see a way to include only those that I need.

Is it possible to update only specific tables and not all?

Comment: By Update, do you mean Refresh the Schema of Specific Tables?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Database first scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302968/can-entity-framework-4-1-designer-update-model-from-database-for-selected-entit/

Answer (score 5):

Sadly no. Refresh updates all of the mapped tables. You can choose not to import new ones, but EF thinks keeping its model and the database in sync is a good idea. I guess you could dive into the XML behind, grab copies of what you don't want to change, and then put them back afterwards, but thats beyond my experience.

EDIT: 
From the possible duplicate question above, an external tool http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/ is referenced which looks like it would do the job.

Comment: This is true, the UI is confusing.  I've actually done this: update from the model, then using my source-control I see what lines have changed and revert any I don't want.  It's very easy to mess up the file, but if you're careful you can pick which changes you want.  Not ideal, but possible.

Comment: I do the same, but it sucks :(